# How to stop MS Visual Studio Express 2013 from overwriting save files automatically

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Whenever I do some changes to my program and run it in debug mode, I cannot go back to before the changes. ctrl+z does not work(grayed out) and opening the project or file also doesn't work.
Is there a way to stop it from overwriting my savefiles? Do I have to save it with another name each time I try something new?

Comment: You need to have [**Version Control**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181368.aspx)

Comment: Try going to Tools -> Option -> Environment -> Keyboard -> Press "Reset" and restart VS to see if Ctrl Z will work. As suggested, get to use source code version control.

Comment: Okay, thanks! So many thing to learn.. Need to do some reading now then.

Comment: Just to clarify: you're running into this without closing anything, right?  Just edit a file, hit F5, and you can no longer undo your edits?  You should be able to stop debugging, and then undo your changes in that scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run a program you need to build it, and to build it, you need to recompile your program from source, this requires that the files be saved, otherwise debugging wouldn't work because the files wouldn't match the code being executed.

If you want to make changes as you debug, look at "Edit and Continue", or copying+pasting your changes to a notepad window as a temporary buffer.

...and use source-control.